# What is the query used to know the actives databases in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I want to know the actives databases in all databases I have(I'm using xampp)

the command SHOW Databases , it shows all databases without knowing they are all active or not

Comment: There's only ONE active database associated with any given connection; the one shown with `SELECT DATABASE()`

Answer (score 1):

The [DATABASE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_database) function does what you want.

```sql
SELECT DATABASE();
```

Comment: The OP talks about multiple databases, plural. I'm not sure what they think they want.

Comment: Yeah, I know the question is vague. I'm kind of hoping OP will follow the link and learn about informational functions.